# Hyper-V cannot ping VM from host

Tags: hyper-v, nic

I have a small Hyper-V environment, but since today I cannot ping from the VM to outside, and not from the local network to the VM.

My situation/network in short:

- Router: 192.168.1.254
- My Hyper-V Host/Computer: 192.168.1.10
- My Virtual Machine: 192.168.168.1.110
- They ALL have gw=192.168.1.254, subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
- None of the computers have the windows firewall enabled
- The VM is connected via a external Virtual Switch, that is bound to
  my only NIC in my PC. (Allow management operating system to share
  this NIC = on)
- I always ping using the IP

From my computer (192.168.1.10) I can ping all components in the network, like GW and others. But I cannot ping the VM.

From the VM, I can ping the default gateway, and other VM's, but none of the other NIC's in the network, for example 192.168.1.10

This used to work, I didn't change anything, and it stoped working. I think this has to do with the virtual switch of Hyper-V, anybody have a tip on where to look?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Long story short: remove the virtual switch from Hyper-V, recreate it, and everything worked again...

Comment: Indeed, solved the issue.

Comment: Solved for me also.

Comment: Still a working solution more than years later on the latest Win 10 Insider build.

Comment: Had the same issue. Everything worked, I didn't change anything. Then it broke. I could ping the VM from another computer, but not from the local machine (the same thing with HTTP access). Very funny, yeah? Recreating the virtual switch solved the problem!

Comment: Yep good. killed it and made it again. Worked.

Comment: Recreation creates a new Ethernet interface. Looks like something went wrong during Hyper-V installation. And, yes, recreation does help.

Answer (score 3):

reason is!!Firewall!!

Disable Firewall, or to be specific in the firewall settings, allow bellow app to communicate through fire wall and issue will be resolved:

File and Printer Sharing (ICMS)

Comment: in my case the rule was "File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)"

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me after host system update. VM client is Windows 7 and must have seen the updated virtual switch as a new network. Recreating virtual switch as above didn't work for me. Solution for me was to either

(1) within VM, set network location from Private to Home

-- or --

(2) within VM, allow network discovery in Private

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a virtual switch, each adapter will show duplicated on the host level, one is the physical itself and the other the virtual version of it.

You probably have a local ip on the physical adapter when it should not even have a TCP protocol.

Set up your local ip on the virtual adapter and check again.